# Supervisor gives too short a time to finish tasks

Tags: communication, team, software-development, time-management, task-management

I just got a job as a web programmer at this company. This is my first job. During the interview, they asked me to create a website, I created one using HTML and JavaScript.

As I started working, I got a task requiring LotusScript, not JavaScript. I don't know LotusScript but I am fine with that because I can learn new things, as long as I have time to do so before the deadline. But the task time-frame is just two weeks from the next day I started.

How I am supposed to learn it and finish within these two weeks? I tried to communicate with the supervisor to extend the deadline but they just kept it at two weeks. I want to ask my senior programmer but for this month they are just busy with meetings and their jobs and I have to learn by myself and finish it within two weeks.

Now I only have one week left and the task is not yet complete. Any help explaining how to manage finishing the task within the allotted time would be appreciated. Or any tips on how to communicate with coworkers about this.

Comment: What steps have you taken to learn LotusScript during the past week?

Comment: I have learned the basic thing about LotusScript and everything related to the task. The task given related to old company project. I need to add new functionality to the project. I'm stuck because some technical part needs some help from my senior programmer to understand. But as I mention, my senior programmer keeps busy with their meeting and work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you're in need of help (technical) and you need to ask for it. The best time to do it was yesterday. (You need to do it RIGHT NOW!!)

Understand this (in general): Everyone is busy and have their own work, you need to make it as easy as possible for them to help you. For example,

- You walk up to someone who is in middle of work and ask to explain a whole chapter (or the workflow of a whole module in the project), no one will be ready to help you as that is going to take a,lot of time. Instead, if you have a specific question that can be answered quickly, people would be more inclined to help you by answering that.
- Make sure you show your efforts before you reach for help. Show your research efforts, what you tried and how it failed. People like to help them who helps themselves.

Also, don't go the verbal way, as clearly it did not work. Write down sequentially

- What is the expected outcome from you
- What you already did (or tried)
- Where you are stuck
- What help you think you'll need to make progress

and send it to your senior, with a copy to your supervisor.

*Don't complain or sound like you're complaining*, that's not going to solve anything, you need help and you need to make sure you get that. Help people to help you.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the advice.  Will working on it right now.

Comment: +1 for not asking them in the middle of another task they are on. Schedule something on their calendar when you provide your questions so both of you have time to prepare.

Answer (score 4):

You should have told them right away that you **don't know the language** but are **willing to learn** it on the project which obviously means you **need more time**.

**NOW** you need to tell them that **you won't** be able to **make the deadline** because learning the new language took more time than you anticipated.

**Ask for help or replacement to ensure a delivery on time.**